# JSTree Proton theme Change icon to folder open and close

Tags: javascript, css, jstree

I just have one demo application in which JSTree with proton theme is used.

I want to change the icon when node is open to folder open and when node is closed to folder closed.

Same like following.
 [Proton CMS ADMIN PANEL](http://proton.orangehilldev.com/documentation.html#fonts-and-icons)

Check the documentation node in there it changes icon to folder open and closed.

Now when i am trying to change icon i found that it is using CSS Sprites and when i checked style.css i found that it is also using base64 url to load some images.

[image]

here is the sprites it has used.

**How can i use that directory open and close icon in node?**

**What are the names or css class to use for that icon?**

**when we are having sprite how we can find icon name and load it?**

Apart from that i also want to use that filled square for leaf node icon.

I am able to render that image using following sprite code.

```
.jstree-folder-open {
background: url('32px.png') no-repeat -531px -23px !important;
}
```

**But still unable to display icon in correct size and correct way. Is there any particular way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to render image by just changing background position in css.

Here is the tool by which i found the css code to render image from sprite.

[Sprite Cow](http://www.spritecow.com/)

Open your image and select portion.

After that i just created seperate class and used background-position css.

```
.jstree-folder-open {
background-image: url('32px.png') !important;
background-position: -105px -70px !important;
}

.jstree-folder-closed {
background-image: url('32px.png') !important;
background-position: -261px -7px !important;
}

li.jstree-leaf > a > i.jstree-icon {
background-image: url('32px.png') !important;
background-position: -200px -7px !important;
}
```